# How do I specifiy the table prefix when using wp-load.php?

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins

I'm trying to use Wordpress data outside of Wordpress, to create new users and login, when people to do the same for my website.

How do I specify the table prefix when using wp-load.php?

This code causes this error.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require("council/wp-load.php");
```

> Table 'yprice_wrdp1.users' doesn't exist

The table prefix is `_wp`, so basically, Wordpress or wp-load.php, should actually be looking for the `wp_users` table instead of the `users` table.

So how do I specifiy the table prefix to look for?

*I've searched using Google, Stack Exchange, Wordpress forum and codex, and I can't find anything. :/*

PS. Yes the table prefix is correctly defined in wp.config.php, and my Wordpress installation works.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. I included the required Wordpress code, before my config.php database connect code, and now it works.